# Android ImageRotation with Image-snippet?

Tags: android, image, animation, android-animation

I would like to create a very specific animation on Android.

The animation looks like this:

[image: Bilder oder Fotos hochladen]
[image: Bilder oder Fotos hochladen]
[image: Bilder oder Fotos hochladen]

My first Idea was to get 2 Images, one from Pizza and one of the wrap, and animate a rotation of the snippet like a clipPath in SVG.

Can you give me some tips?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<animation-list>` drawable XML together with `AnimationDrawable`:

```
private ImageButton runSim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        runSim = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.runSim);
        //....
        Tools.executeAsyncTask(new RunSimAnimationTask());
        //....
}


private boolean simExecuted = false;
private AnimationDrawable runSimAnimation = null;

private class RunSimAnimationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AnimationDrawable>{


    @Override
    protected AnimationDrawable doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        AnimationDrawable animations = new AnimationDrawable();
        animations = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animate_sim);
        animations.setOneShot(false);
        return animations;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AnimationDrawable animationDrawables) {
        super.onPostExecute(animationDrawables);

        runSimAnimation = animationDrawables;

        registerRunSimClickListener();

    }
}

private void registerRunSimClickListener() {

    runSim.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.performClick();
            }

            else {

            }

            return true;
        }

    });

    runSim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            MainChatController.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    simExecuted = !simExecuted;

                    if (simExecuted) {
                        startSimulationAnimation();
                    }
                    else {
                        stopSimulationAnimation();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public void startSimulationAnimation() {
    MainChatController.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runSim.setImageDrawable(runSimAnimation);
            runSimAnimation.start();
        }
    });
}

public void stopSimulationAnimation() {
    MainChatController.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runSim.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_data_usage));
            runSimAnimation.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

Tools.executeAsyncTask():

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
static public <T> void executeAsyncTask(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task, T... params) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    }
    else {
        task.execute(params);
    }
}
```

res/drawable/animate_sim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the animation list must have more than one item -->
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animate_sim_rotation" android:duration="0" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animate_sim_rotation" android:duration="2000" />
</animation-list>
```

The `<animation-list>` above will animate a drawable `<animated-rotate>` below:

res/drawable/animate_sim_rotation.xml:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_data_usage"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
```

But, you can replace the items in the `<animation-list>` with actual image files in successive frames.

Comment: If i get the information correctly, then i have to make many pictures... is this correct? But how many will get a fluid animation...?